# Magento PHP pages not refreshing

Tags: php, magento

I'm using Magento to build our EC site.
And I found our product page is not refreshing when I enable "Full Page Cache".

For example, I do this in the first line:

```
echo time();
```

but it always shows the same timestamp no matter how many time I refresh the browser.
(And I already disable the cache function in my browser)

But the funny thing is when I append any parameter to my url,
for example

> mysite/?a=0

The timestamp is updated accordingly.

Is this the expected scenario with Magento framework?
Or did I just get something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**That's right!**
You need to develop a store without cache function.
At the end you can turn it on. This cache is intended to user